# clean install Windows 10 on Surface Laptop

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, microsoft-surface

I have a Surface Laptop (1st gen). I want to restore it to factory condition.

I used "Surface Recovery Image Download" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-recovery-image) to create a USB recovery drive with "Windows 10 Pro in S Mode Version 1703".

I can boot from the USB recovery drive (using Volume Down + Power key). From there, I go to Troubleshoot > Recover from a drive > Fully clean the drive > Recover. It spins for a while and then fails with the message:

"There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made."

I tried deleting all partitions on the primary disk using diskpart, and also running bootrec /FixBoot (which appears to succeed). But the issue persists.

What else should I try? How can I do a "clean" install of Windows on this device?

Comment: As mentioned I have now deleted all the partitions, so the system currently does not have an OS to boot into. But I had previously attempted reset from Settings and got the same error.

The Surface Recovery Image Download page presents only three options: Version 1703, Version 1709, and Version 1803. I picked 1703 just because it was the version at the time the device was purchased. Do you think I'd have better luck with one of the others?

Comment: This didn't work, but it gave me more clues that helped me get it working. The 21H1 installation media (created from https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10 > Download tool now) produced the error "Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration." Furthermore, the keyboard did not work at all, so I was unable to use the command prompt. But the bcdboot workaround described at https://www.wintips.org/fix-windows-could-not-update-the-computers-boot-configuration/ was successful with the version 1703 Surface Recovery Image.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following these steps after the appearance of the message "There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made."

1. Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Prompt
2. Run:

```
cd /d S:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
ren BCD BCD.bak
bcdboot W:\Windows /l en-us /s S: /f UEFI
```

3. Hold Power key for 30 sec (hard power OFF)
4. Unplug USB drive
5. Power ON